# Copy data from one table to another while at the same time insert a guid SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have over 13,000 records in an existing table called "AnyName"

I need to move the records to a new table Called "DomainObject2" New, this table will have a Guid primary column named "Oid"

I get the following error when i execute the below code.

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Oid', table 'NewDatabase.dbo.DomainObject2'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

````
    USE NewDatabase

INSERT INTO NewDatabase.dbo.DomainObject2

 ([Ano]
           ,[C1]
           ,[C2]
           ,[C3]
           ,[C4]
           ,[C5]
           ,[CF]
           ,[CF2]
           ,[CF3]
           ,[CF4]
           ,[CF5])
SELECT 
[ano]
           ,[c1]
           ,[c2]
           ,[c3]
           ,[c4]
           ,[c5]
           ,[cf]
           ,[cf2]
           ,[cf3]
           ,[cf4]
           ,[cf5]
FROM AnyName.dbo.[Old_Table]; 

GO```



Thanks in advance!!!
````

Comment: You have 11 columns in your insert list, but 13 in your select list. That's going to throw a run time error before it ever gets to a data issue, so I think we may not have a complete picture here of what's happening.

Comment: there are many more columns than you can see but their all the same don't worry abut the amount of columns but thanks! Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO NewDatabase.dbo.DomainObject2

 ([Oid]
           ,[Ano]
           ,[C1]
           ,[C2]
           ,[C3]
           ,[C4]
           ,[C5]
           ,[CF]
           ,[CF2]
           ,[CF3]
           ,[CF4]
           ,[CF5])
SELECT     NewID()
           ,[ano]
           ,[c1]
           ,[c2]
           ,[c3]
           ,[c4]
           ,[c5]
           ,[cf]
           ,[cf2]
           ,[cf3]
           ,[cf4]
           ,[cf5]
FROM AnyName.dbo.[Old_Table];
```

Comment: Hello and thank you! rumata28, did you tried this?

cause i got this new error

The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Since i had to add the Oid Column to the new table, there is now one more column on the NewTable

Comment: @Luk - Try this it will work, because you are not select guid column and in required table in which you are inserting from old table, [oid] will be required or not null field.. thatswhy you must be getting error... Kindly try the above query and then update to us.  Thanks.

Comment: Your are right, sorry, I did not try - I would, if you provide "create table" for your tables.  Indeed, select had 2 more columns (did I copy it from your original post?).  Anyway, please make sure the selected columns (including the very first `NewID()` expression, which selects value for the `Oid` column and insert columns match each other to meet your requirements.

Comment: rumata28, i did edit the original message to remove the extra columns, but i'm still getting the same error  The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns. and i have the same columns including the Oid in the insert to statement and the NewID() after the select Statement

Comment: did I mention the Oid is a guid?

Comment: Could you please put the exact query your are trying to execute (the most recent version), which gives that error message?

Comment: `USE NewDatabase


INSERT INTO NewDatabase.dbo.DomainObject2

 ([Oid]
           ,[ano]
           ,[c1]
           ,[c2]
           ,[c3]
           ,[c4]
           ,[c5]
           ,[cf]
           ,[cf2]
           ,[cf3]
           ,[cf4]
           ,[cf5])

SELECT  NewID()
[ano]
           ,[c1]
           ,[c2]
           ,[c3]
           ,[c4]
           ,[c5]
           ,[cf]
           ,[cf2]
           ,[cf3]
           ,[cf4]
           ,[cf5]
 
FROM AnyName.dbo.[Old_Table]; `

Comment: please add a comma after `NewID()`

Comment: Yes! that was it, sorry i don't know anything about SQL Thank you very much rumata28

Comment: you should edit your post to include the coma after the NewID(),

Comment: I actually do have the comma, but it is on the next line (right before the `[ano]` column) - to match query formatting in your initial question.